# Почему в jupyter не отображаются линии графа, лишь точки

Tags: python, графы, jupyter-notebook, networkx

Почему в jupyter не отображаются линии графа, лишь точки? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]![введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете вместо картинок вставить код в виде текста? И еще приведите пожалуйста вывод команды `print(G.edges())` в вопросе

Comment: def prepare_table_graph(table):
    Nodes_list=[]
    Edges_list=[]
    n=len(table)
    Nodes_list=[i+1 for i in range (n)]
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range (n):
            if table[i][j]==1:
                Edges_list.append((i+1,j+1))
    return Nodes_list, Edges_list
n=int(input())
a=[]
for i in range (n):
    b=list(map(int,input().split()))
    a.append(b)
Nodes_list, Edges_list=prepare_table_graph(a)
print(Nodes_list, Edges_list)
import networkx

Comment: from networkx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(Nodes_list)
G.add_edges_from(Edges_list)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=None, arrows=True, with_labels=True)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой «править» под вопросом, чтобы вставить код в тело вопроса. В комментариях невозможно отформатировать код...

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, что публикуя картинки вместо кода, вы не только снижаете вероятность получить ответ, но также рискуете тем, что для вашей учётной записи будет заблокирована возможность задать новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу воспроизвести вашу картинку без ребер:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

adj_table = [[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
node_names = [1,2,3]

# создаем граф из матрицы смежности
G = nx.from_numpy_array(np.array(adj_table), create_using=nx.DiGraph)                                                                        

# переименовываем узлы графа
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(zip(G.nodes(), node_names)))

# рисуем граф
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=None, arrows=True, with_labels=True)
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]